# ExpandableListView not displaying selected/focused rows correctly

Tags: android

I have an ExpandableListView defined with:

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/MyListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/mylistview_selectable"
/>
```

drawable/mylistview_selectable.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF4" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#4FF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#D0F" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and the ExpandableListView's OnChildClickListener has:

```
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    MyListView.setSelectedChild(groupPosition, childPosition, true);        
    return true;
}
```

where GameList is:

```
ExpandableListView MyListView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.MyListView);
```

However, when I press on a child item, the background briefly changes to the `state_pressed` color before going back to the default background.  Neither the `state_focused` nor the `state_selected` colors ever appear.

I tried using `setItemChecked` and `state_checked`, but that didn't work either.

How do you set a "selected" item's background (so that it unsets itself when it is no longer selected)?

Comment: For keeping the item selected try state_enabled = "true" and to check the state_focused run it on emulator and use keyboard buttons to get your focus on the list item.

Comment: I tried state_enabled, but that "flashes" the color.  Nothing seems to keep it in any particular state (except that holding the button down keeps it in the state_pressed state).